# What is the equivalent of dynamic_cast in Delphi?

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

In Delphi, what is the equivalent of C++'s `dynamic_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, and `static_cast` operators (especially when used on objects)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### reinterpret_cast

Most of the time, in Delphi, a cast is a `reinterpret_cast`, i.e. the bits and bytes of one type are reinterpreted as if it were another type, e.g. `Integer(myEnum)` or `Pointer(MyDynamicArrayVar)`.

Some casts cut off bits, i.e. `Integer(MyInt64)` will cut off the top 32 bits of the `Int64`, and the top bit of the lower 32 bits will become the new sign bit. Some casts expand, e.g. `Integer(myByte)`, although such conversions to a larger type don't require a cast. Conversions from, e.g. `Integer` to floating point don't require casts either.

But sometimes it is not a `reinterpret_cast`, and the cast does a real conversion (e.g. a cast from `string` to `PChar` converts if the string is empty; a cast from `AnsiString` to `UTF8String` converts the contents to UTF-8, and `UnicodeString(myAnsiChar)` converts even twice, from `AnsiChar` to `AnsiString` to `UnicodeString`, although these steps may not all be visible). And some casts are simply not allowed (e.g. `Int64(MyDouble)` or certain casts where the sizes don't match).

Note that with operator overloading (mainly for records), you can have explicit and implicit conversions too. The explicit conversions take the form of a cast. The implicit conversions can be forced by "casting" too.

The form of a cast in Delphi is always `typename(cast_object)`, which casts `cast_object` to `typename`.

Some invalid casts can be circumvented using pointers. If you do something like:

```
MyInt64 := PInt64(@MyDouble)^;
```

*where `PInt64` is a pointer to `Int64` and the other types are obvious*,

then you can cast a `Double` to an `Int64`. Note that *no actual pointer juggling is done*. The conversion is direct, **as if** you had done

```
MyInt64 := Int64(MyDouble); // Invalid typecast -- except in some versions
```

There is no extra kind of `static_cast` in Delphi. I personally wish we had such explicit casts like in C++. Delphi's are more like in C.

### dynamic_cast

If the types involved are classes or interfaces, then there are equivalents using the `as` and `is` keywords. For example:

```
myEdit := MyTObject as TEdit;
myIntf := MyObj as ISomeInterface;
```

both dynamic upcasts. Unlike in C++, these will raise (throw in C++) an `EInvalidCast` exception if `MyTObject` is not an instance of `TEdit`, or if `myObj` doesn't *implement* `ISomeInterface`. It is otherwise equivalent to C++:

```
TEdit *myEdit = dynamic_cast<TEdit *>(MyTObject);
if (myEdit == NULL) throw ...
```

Querying, like often done with `dynamic_cast` in C++, can be done with `is`:

```
if MyObject is TEdit then
  TEdit(MyObject).Text := 'Hello, world!';
```

That is more or less equivalent to this "pattern" in C++:

```
TEdit *e = dynamic_cast<TEdit *>(MyObject);
if (e != NULL)
    e->Text = "Hello, world!";
```

Comment: In the case of polymorphism, there is a direct equivalent for `dynamic_cast` for objects - [the `is` and `as` operators](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_References#The_is_Operator). `if obj is T then` is equivalent to `if (dynamic_cast<T*>(obj) != NULL)` whereas `obj as T` is equivalent to `T* pT = dynamic_cast<T*>(obj); if (pT == NULL) throw ...;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau or just `&dynamic_cast<T&>(*ptr)`

Comment: It would be good to add hard casts to your answer. e.g. `myEdit := TEdit(MyTObject)` which is like a `static_cast` but for objects.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont touché :-)