# How to write equivalent of Delphi "is" and "as" in C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder

I want to write a function (or even an operator, if possible) that is doing something similar to Delphi's "is".
Delphi example:

```
 if Sender is TMenuItem then 
   TMenuItem(Sender)->Enabled = false;
```

So, in C++ **Builder** this would be something like:

```
bool Is(*p1, *p2)
{
    p = dynamic_cast<p1*>(p2);      //here we typecast TObject to TMenuItem
    if (!!p)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

How can I make the function accept any kind of objects for p1, p2?

Comment: Do you just want to find out if `A` is a base class of `B`? If so, consider [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of). If you just want to accept arbitrary types, look for [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates)

Comment: In C++ the "correct" way is to *not* test for classes, and instead use virtual member functions.

Comment: I do not understand why this questions is being downvoted: it is well formulated and makes sense. Just because what OP wants is not the best way to proceed in C++, it does not mean the question itself is bad.

Comment: @AGNGazer - It is known that StackOverflow is one of the most harshest communities online :(      https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Comment: Maybe, but I do not think this is generalizable. But downvoting reasonable questions just because these _seem_ silly to (I assume) "experts" results in people being afraid of asking questions. If they know the answer they should just post it (I assume it would be easy for these experts to craft a brief answer). I saw you had 3 downvotes and so I would have expected three "trivial" answers from these experts.

Comment: @AGNGazer - many problems on SO would be solved if the down-voters will receive a higher "fine" for downvoting without posting (comment or answer) and if the downvote will not be anonymous.

Comment: @AGNGazer - and yes, you are right, SO is not good for beginners!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Not a downvoter, but this question seems prone to start a discussion (i.e. whether or not should we try to do such things). And normally, if I flag a question, I don't see the need for explaining it further - close reason will be enough if my flag was helpful, and any comment will be invalid if my flag wasn't correct.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen - then see: hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Comment: C++ Builder has methods for any TObject descendant:  TObject * Obj;
 Obj->ClassName();
  Obj->ClassNameIs("TMenuItem"); (bool)

Comment: See this recent answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52648049/what-is-the-equivalent-of-dynamic-cast-in-delphi/52648427#52648427 the dynamic_cast part.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Not in C++Builder, which often has to interface with Delphi-based objects. There you do something like: `TMenuItem *m = dynamic_cast<TMenuItem *>(Sender); if (m != NULL) { m->Enabled = false; }`. Sender is a Delphi-based object **passed to you**, declared as `TObject *`, and 1. you don't control it and 2. it doesn't have any virtual functions.

Comment: @Vancalar: using a text comparison when a simple dynamic_cast will do is overkill, IMO. And you may want to match subclasses (descendants) of TMenuItem as well, and then such a text comparison doesn't work. But a dynamic_cast does.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: Sure thing, i just wanted to point out that there are many "Delphi like" methods built in TObject which may be helpfull in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q:** How can I make the function accept any kind of objects for p1, p2?

**A:** Use a template, like this:

```
template<typename T, typename PtrType>
bool IsA(PtrType *ptr)
{
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(ptr) != nullptr;
}
```

Use the templated function like this:

```
A* obj = new C();
if (IsA<C>(obj))
{
        std::cout << "obj is of type C";
}
```

With that said, I advise you to avoid creating such a function for 2 reasons:

1. You could just use the dynamic_cast eveywhere, it's more idiomatic and shows you the cost you are paying to do this kind of check
2. Checking for the specific type is in general a sign of a flawed design. There are some cases when it's needed, but that's rare, and in general my personal opinion is that it shouldn't be condoned in general, which such a function would do.

Comment: To point 2: yes, it is bad OO, but in this case, you get **passed** a pointer of declared type `(TObject *sender)`, but in reality, it can be, say, a `TMenuItem*` or a `TAction*`, so sometimes you must cast. -- But I fully agree that using `dynamic_cast` is the way to go here, because even if e.g. `IsA<TMenuItem>(Sender)` succeeds, to get at the functionality, you have to do a `dynamic_cast`, anyway, so nothing is saved.

Comment: This might be the case - I haven't used C++ Builder, which is why I answered the question to the best of my ability and gave my personal opinion. I believe my advice still stands: Unless strictly needed, avoid dynamic cast. Try to constrain its usage to where absolutely needed, so that it doesn't propagate everywhere in your system. Don't create a function which would facilitate a pattern where it's being used everywhere.

Comment: I don't think the risk is that big. Delphi has `is` and `as`, which fulfill the two uses of `dynamic_cast`. I hardly see any code that really abuses it, or where its use permeates the entire code. It is really only used where appropriate and absolutely necessary. And I have seen **a lot** of Delphi code.